Not able to link PR with tasks in Github Projects
I'm curious if it's possible to link a Pull Request (PR) with a task created within a GitHub Project. While I've managed to manually link tasks with existing PRs, I'm encountering difficulty in linking a PR with tasks that I manually create in a GitHub Project. The issue arises because I typically plan tasks ahead of time, before the corresponding PRs are created. As a result, when I create tasks in the project's To-Do category, there's no PR available to link them to at that moment. Consequently, I end up having to delete those tasks, as I have to manually link Project with newly created PRs which creates a new task in the project (leading to duplicacy).
So, please let me know if I can link a PR directly with a Task in Github Projects interface itself.
(Not able to upload image on Stackoverflow, so please find the here)
I have tried to link project directly with Tasks in Github Projects using the in-built Linked Pull Requests column in Github Project (Table view) but it does not work.
